# Typescript map over list of functions

Tags: javascript, typescript

Coming from a Haskell background, I would like to map over a list of functions. For example I have:

```
functions fnA(x){ return true }
function  fnB(x){ return false }

// I would like to write this code that applies the same value to all functions
[ fnA, fnB ] .map ( (fn : any) => fn('hello world') )
```

However I am getting error:

```
(x : any) => boolean' cannot be used as an index type.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prefix the last line with a semicolon:

`;[ fnA, fnB ] .map ( (fn : any) => fn('hello world') )`

Background: semicolons are optional in Javascript. However there are some edge-cases which require you to apply some style rules.

Starting a line with a bracket `[` or parenthesis `(` is one of those edge cases.